# Пишу игры змейка на C#, нужна помощь с потоками

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу змейку на c# и хотелось бы сделать так чтобы змейка и фроги были разными потоками и когда змея съедает фрога, то поток фрога убивается
пока никаких идей

```
namespace Snake
{
    public class Frog : BaseModel
    {
        private int _height;
        private int _width;

        public Frog(int x, int y)
        {
            _width = x;
            _height = y;
            points = new List<Point>();
        }

        public void AddFrog(int x = 0, int y = 0)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(unchecked((int)DateTime.Now.Millisecond));
            if (x == 0 && y == 0)
                do
                {
                    x = rand.Next(_width);
                    y = rand.Next(_height);
                } while (x == 0 || y == 0);
            points.Add(new Point(x, y, Models.Frog));

        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            points.Clear();
        }
        public Point GetPoint()
        {
            if (points.Count == 1)
                return points[0];
            else
                return null;
        }

        public override void Draw()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

```
    public class Game : BaseModel
    {
        private int _width;
        private int _height;
        private Snake _snake;
        private Frog _frog;
        private GameMode _gameMode;

        public int Size { get { return _snake.points.Count; } }

        public int FrogCount { get; private set; }

        public Game()
        {
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            points = new List<Point>();
            _frog = new Frog(_width, _height);
            Draw();
        }

        public void ChangeDirection(Directions direction)
        {
            _snake.DirectionControl = direction;
        }

        public bool Move()
        {
            bool res;
            var frogPoint = _frog.points;
            res = _snake.Move(ref frogPoint);
            // Добавление frog на карту
            if (frogPoint.Count < FrogCount)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < FrogCount - frogPoint.Count; i++)
                {
                    Random rand = new Random(unchecked((int)DateTime.Now.Millisecond));
                    int x;
                    int y;
                    var points = GetAllPoints();
                    do
                    {
                        x = rand.Next(_width);
                        y = rand.Next(_height);
                    } while (points.Exists(p => p.X == x && p.Y == y && p.Model != Models.Empty));
                    _frog.AddFrog(x, y);
                }
            }
            return res;
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            throw new System.AggregateException();
        }

        public void Сontinue()
        {
            throw new System.AggregateException();
        }

        public void CreateFood()
        {
            throw new System.AggregateException();
        }

        public void Exit()
        {
            throw new System.AggregateException();

        }

        public void LoadLevel(int level = 0)
        {
            if (level == 0)
            {
                FrogCount = 10;
                EditSittings(GameMode.HitWall, 30, 25);
                _snake = new Snake(5, _width, _height, Directions.Right, _gameMode);
            }
        }




        public void EditSittings(GameMode gameMode, int width, int heigth)
        {
            _gameMode = gameMode;
            _width = width;
            _height = heigth;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Получить все точки игры
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<Point> GetAllPoints()
        {
            var allPoints = new List<Point>();
            allPoints.AddRange(points);
            allPoints.AddRange(_snake.points);
            allPoints.AddRange(_frog.points);

            return allPoints;
        }

        public override void Draw()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _width; i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(i, 0, Models.Wall));
                points.Add(new Point(i, _height, Models.Wall));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(0, i, Models.Wall));
                points.Add(new Point(_width, i, Models.Wall));
            }
            points.Add(new Point(_width, _height, Models.Wall));
            for (int i = 1; i < _width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < _height; j++)
                {
                    if (points.Find(x => x.X == i && x.Y == j) == null)
                        points.Add(new Point(i, j, Models.Empty));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
  internal class Snake : BaseModel
    {
        public Directions _direction;
        public int _lenght;
        public int _width;
        public int _height;
        public GameMode _gameMod;
        public Directions DirectionControl { get; set; }

        public Snake(int lengthSnake, int width, int height, Directions direction, GameMode gameMod)
        {
            if (width <= 0)
                throw new Exception();
            if (height <= 0)
                throw new Exception();
            if (height <= 0)
                throw new Exception();
            if (lengthSnake >= width || lengthSnake >= height)
                throw new Exception("Length of snake not be more size place ");
            _width = width;
            _height = height;
            _direction = direction;
            _gameMod = gameMod;
            _lenght = lengthSnake;

            Draw();

        }

        public bool Move(ref List<Point> frogPoints)
        {
            if (points.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("Length of snake not be null ");
            int x = points.Last().X;
            int y = points.Last().Y;

            // Запрет разворота на 180
            // Если попытка поворота на 180 градусов
            if ((_direction == Directions.Right && DirectionControl == Directions.Left) ||
                (_direction == Directions.Left && DirectionControl == Directions.Right) ||
                (_direction == Directions.Up && DirectionControl == Directions.Down) ||
                (_direction == Directions.Down && DirectionControl == Directions.Up))
            {
                //_direction;
            }
            else
            {
                _direction = DirectionControl;
            }
            switch (_direction)
            {
                case Directions.Up:
                    y -= 1;
                    break;
                case Directions.Down:
                    y += 1;
                    break;
                case Directions.Left:
                    x -= 1;
                    break;
                case Directions.Right:
                    x += 1;
                    break;
            }
            bool confused = false;
            bool hitTheWall = false;

            // TODO учесть GameMod

            // Проверка. Врежется в стену или в свое тело
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                confused = (point.X == x && point.Y == y);
                hitTheWall = (x > _width - 1 || x < 1) || (y > _height - 1 || y < 1);
                if (confused || hitTheWall)
                    break;
            }
            // Проверка. Сьест еду. 
            bool frogEated = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < frogPoints.Count; i++)
            {
                // Поела, хвост не удаляется
                if (frogPoints[i].X == x && frogPoints[i].Y == y)
                {
                    frogPoints.Remove(frogPoints[i]);
                    points[0].Model = Models.Tail;
                    points.Last().Model = Models.Body;
                    frogEated = true;
                }

            }
            // Осталась голодной, хвост удаляется
            if (!frogEated)
            {
                points.RemoveAt(0);
                points[0].Model = Models.Tail;
                points.Last().Model = Models.Body;
            }

            // Добавляем голову 
            points.Add(new Point(x, y, Models.Head));

            if (confused || hitTheWall)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

        public override void Draw()
        {
            int startWidth = 1;
            int startHeight = 1;
            points = new List<Point>();

            for (int i = 0; i < _lenght; i++)
            {
                // Add Tail
                if (i == 0)
                    points.Add(new Point(startWidth + i, startHeight, Models.Tail));
                // Add Head
                else if (i == _lenght - 1)
                    points.Add(new Point(startWidth + i, startHeight, Models.Head));
                // Add Body
                else
                    points.Add(new Point(startWidth + i, startHeight, Models.Body));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Кто такие Фроги и зачем им быть в отдельных потоках?

Comment: @Kromster фрог это лягушка, так производительнее)

Comment: больше потоков не всегда означает большую производительность.

Comment: Хорошо, помогите мне с задачей
а не вопросом нужно ли.
Мне нужно
хотя бы чтобы поиграться с потоками

Comment: Поставил плюс к вопросу. Как минимум потому что самому интересно как кто реализует на шарпе в юнити проэкте работу с потоками) Кстате, как альтернативный вариант можно реализовать некую систему сигналов и попробовать решить ту же задачу через сигналы. Так же чисто с целью обучения.

Comment: Это Unity3D? Добавить тег соответствующий нужно тогда.

Comment: @Andrew, причём здесь Unity? Здесь нет ни единого на него намёка. C# это не только Unity так-то, мягко говоря

Comment: @Kir_Antipov а, это мне уже показалось. Переутомился, наверное. Но все равно интересно как это в шарпе можно красиво реализовать.

Comment: @Andrew, как и на любом другом языке? Начнём с того, что потоки здесь никакие не нужны, ибо "Змейка"  в любой своей вариации спокойно отрисовывается пошагово. Продолжим тем, что с C# 5 Thread стал матерным выражением

Comment: Это неюнити а просто змейка на винформах

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я сейчас работаю с свифтом с одним весьма необычным фрейморком для многопоточности. Ничего общего с шарповой реализацей работы с потоками это не имеет :) Вот прям вообще. Так что я бы не горячился с фразами "как и на любом другом языке". Собственно, в программировании любую задачу можно решить множеством способов, почему это же утверждение не применить и на работу с потоками?) Лично меня даный вопрос заинтересовал как раз с точки зрения того как на шарпе с потоками работают и какие есть оптимальные варианты работы с потоками именно здесь.

Comment: @Andrew, во-первых, фреймворк != язык. Меня прямо перетряхивает, когда кто-то говорит что-то в духе: "Этот фреймворк так не похож на такой-то язык" Это вещи разного порядка. Во-вторых, на языке вы описываете алгоритм, а алгоритм можно переложить на любой язык. Вопрос же здесь заключается не в механике языка, а именно в способе решения задачи. Ну и, как я уже говорил выше, про многопоточность здесь говорить будет лишним: вся игра может (и должна, ибо в обратном нет нужды) обрабатываться единым потоком

Comment: Еще помогите с движением лягушек, я хочу чтобы лягушки двигались как и змея
но не получается так как лягушка это один элемент а не много как змея

Comment: Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 сидит на мейнтреде, а тут человеку с ума со змейкой сходит, аж `фроги` мерещаца.

Answer (score 1):

1. Используй [TPL](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1) Добавь в еще одно поле в класс Frog с типом CancellationTokenSource.
   вызывай код обновления канвы / поиска координат / другие долгие вычисления в потоке.

   var frog = new Frog();
   Task.Run(()=>
   {
   while(!frog.frogEated)
   {
   if(frog.needDraw())frog.Draw();
   frog.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(10);
   }

   }, frog.cts.Token);

Но тут есть ряд нюансов. Рисовать на канве может только основной поток. Чтобы это сделать тебе нужно будет код метода Draw обернуть в делегат (часто так делают рекурсивным методом), который будет вызываться в основном потоке. Когда snake eat frog находи ее токен и вызывай Cancel(). поток связанный с токеном завершиться. Прочитай про lock(){} и volatile т.к. переменные которые могут быть модифицированы из другого потока нужно пометить volatile иначе оптимизация может тебе все сломать. Модификацию оберни в свойство или метод с блокировкой к примерно так:

```
void eat(){lock(frog) {frogEated = true; Cts.cancel();}
```

Пример делегата для изменения свойства Control'а из потока.

```
delegate void controlDelegate();

void updateText()
{
    if (form.InvokeRequired)
    {
        
        controlDelegate del = delegate ()
        {
            form.Text = "Модификация данных из другого потока";
        };
        Invoke(del);
    } else form.Text = "Модификация данных из основного потока";
}
```

2. [Про CancellationToken](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, если производительности хватает с избытком несколько потоков не нужны. Потоки нужны когда необходимо, чтобы приложение или служба не зависли на вводе/выводе или долгом расчете. Или когда нужно независимо опрашивать несколько устройств или работать с несколькими клиентскими подключениями. Если твой код не будет блокировать поток (если код работает в цикле) и не будет задержек на ввод/вывод, то издержки на переключение контекста нивелируют весь профит от потока, производительность упадет особенно если таких потоков будет много. Еще добавятся проблемы с доступом к общим ресурсам из разных потоков и синхронизацией.